# Do I need to specify attributes on deriving classes?

Tags: c++

I have this interface. If I derive, do I need to specify `format attribute` again? And, if a class `Deriv` implements this interface, can I use `Deriv::LT_DEBUG`?

```
class Logger
{
    public:
        enum LogType
        {   
            LT_DEBUG = 0,
            LT_WARNING,
            LT_ERROR,
            LT_STAT,
            LT_TEXT
        };  

        __attribute__((format(printf, 6, 7)))
        virtual const char* EHLog(LogType,
                bool,
                const char*,
                int,
                const char*, 
                ...) = 0;

        virtual ~Logger(){}
};
```

Comment: I've never seen such a thing oO

Comment: It is used to verify whether arguments to your function are correct. If you take variadic argument lists.:)

Comment: @ereOn http://unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html#format

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: Thanks for the link. Really interesting.

Comment: Well, a test shows that the format is not checked if you call specifically the derived class' method without the attribute.

Comment: @ereOn - It's really interesting, yeah. When I first saw that, I was totally shocked (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any documentation on it, but I guess that the `__attribute__` annotation is not implicitly inherited by a derived class.
This means that, if you call `EHLog` through a `Deriv` instance, reference or pointer, the format checking is only done if the `Deriv::EHLog` also specifies the `__attribute__((format))` annotation.

The reason for my guess is that this way the compiler does not have to change its name-lookup mechanism to cope with the possibility of `__attribute__` annotations on the base-class function that is being overridden.

---

As for the second question: Yes, you can access names from the base class using a derived class qualification. `Deriv::LT_DEBUG` should work and resolve to the same name as `Logger::LT_DEBUG`.